# django fuzzy string translation not showing up

Tags: django, internationalization, fuzzy

1. Why sometimes I get a `fuzzy` item in `django.po` language file. Actually, I have checked in my project the `fuzzy` string item is totally unique.

   ```
   #: .\users\views.py:81 .\users\views.py:101
   #, fuzzy
   msgid "username or email"
   msgstr "9988"
   ```
2. It is ok to be fuzzy but my translation of fuzzy item not showing up on the page, only English version shows up. It is totally odd.

Answer (score 44):

---

1. `msgmerge` marks strings as `fuzzy` if the old catalog had a translation for a strings with a similar-looking `msgid`. It also carries over strings marked as fuzzy from an old catalog to a new one.
2. `msgfmt` excludes fuzzy messages from the compiled catalog, as the translations are likely incorrect. The translator should check correctness of the translation (in the case you posted, an empty string is clearly an incorrect translation), and remove the `fuzzy` mark when the translation is is verified. If you absolutely want to use fuzzy translations, pass `--use-fuzzy` to `msgfmt`:

```
python manage.py compilemessages --use-fuzzy
```

Comment: thanks, actually i put something at real translation say msgid "username or email"
msgstr "9988"   and   i use 'django-admin.py compilemessages' command to compile , seems no --use-fuzzy   parameter to pass.

Comment: compilemessages just invokes `msgmft --check-format -o foo.mo foo.po` for all po files it finds. Just use msgfmt explicitly instead.

Comment: It is important to highlight that when you check that fuzzy translations are ok you should remove the fuzzy flag. Otherwise, they will be skipped with normal `compilemessages` calls

Answer (score 7):

I also had these problems and I solved them all by using a 'po editor' (like [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)) which highlights fuzzy and untranslated entries and makes the translation process much faster.

You can also use [Django Rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) to have the translating process integrated in your Django environment.

Answer (score 4):

Very thanks to the 1st answer by **@Martin v. Löwis**.

Yes, that worked great. In my case, using `--use-fuzzy` switch was very useful.

In my case, the content of `.po` file lines (not working) was something like below. All translated lines were working except this.

```
#: ui/templates/theme/html/ltr/vertical-menu-template-nav-dark/login.html:58
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "Already a registered user (Login)"
msgid "Not a registered user (Create account)"
msgstr "Уже зарегистрированный пользователь (логин)"
```

Here is output of my terminal after executing `django-admin compilemessages --use-fuzzy`.

```sh
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$ django-admin compilemessages --use-fuzzy
processing file django.po in /Users/hygull/Projects/Python36/Django/Others/AMCProj/amc/src/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES
processing file django.po in /Users/hygull/Projects/Python36/Django/Others/AMCProj/amc/src/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
processing file django.po in /Users/hygull/Projects/Python36/Django/Others/AMCProj/amc/src/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
```

Finally, after running the command, just  restart the server i.e. `python manage.py runserver`.